# Android Webview URL redirect on some Devices doesn´t work

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

I use a Android Webview and Override the Url Loading:

```
           @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }
```

On a Logout i have the following URL: https://someadress/logout?redirectURL=https%3A%2F%2Fsomeadress.de%2Flogout.html&skinID=no_scr
On some Devices, specially Samsung Devices, the redirect is not working and stops after calling this URL. But on the most Devices the redirect is working.

Anybody has some Idea why the redirect isn´t working on some Kind of Devices?

Comment: I find some Error in my Log: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <" and there my redirect stops. But the Error will only fired when i´m using a Samsung Device.

Answer (score 0):

Try this on. This is working fine for me

`@Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
        context.startActivity(i);
        return true;
    }`

Comment: I think thats not the right way for me, because i don´t want to start a new Activity. I Try to get the redirect in my Activity when the User click the Logout Button in the Webview. I wondering why this is not working on some Samsung Devices, but the rest of Devices works fine.

Comment: But there is only option to use this for open url in new webview

Comment: But the URL should be shown in the existing Webview where the User is.

Comment: Than use only return false instead of return true.

Answer (score 0):

You are loading the same URL. That is not an override. If you are returning true, you need to load a different URL.